# Backbone.history.navigate disregard trigger:false

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I try to study and use Backbone/Marionette in my project. Now I stuck with Router navigation which work not as I though it should.

```
class MyApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes :
        'info/:place/(:what)' : 'places_page'

MyApp.Controller = ->
    places_page: (place,what)->
        console.log 'Triggered places_page'


MyApp.addInitializer( ->
    controller = new MyApp.Controller()
    new MyApp.Router
        controller: controller
    Backbone.history.start( pushState: false )
    )


MyApp.vent.on('do:search', ->
    console.log 'triggered do:search'
    place = 'Moscow'
    what = 'Пицца'
    info_model.set place: place, item:what
    new_url = 'info/'+where+'/'+what
    if new_url != decodeURIComponent(Backbone.history.fragment)
        Backbone.history.navigate(new_url, {trigger: false})
```

On initial load of site.com/#info/Budapest/Vine page or reload it, I get `Triggered places_page` message as I expect.

But when I fire `do:search` event which update url to site.com/#info/Moscow/Пицца, I get `Triggered places_page` again! So it reload all my views from scratch instead of just change url and re-render one model.

What I can do wrong here?

**Update 2:**
Found strange thing. If I use latin letters in new url, everything work like it should.
But if I use cyrillic in new url path, it will trigger route function.

*Backbone: 1.0, Marionette:v1.0.3, jquery: 1.9.1*

Comment: How are you initialize your Backbone.History ?

Comment: `Backbone.history.start( pushState: false )` , if I understand you correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mystery solved!

That happens because of non-latin symbols in url.
Correct code:

```
new_url = 'info/'+encodeURIComponent(where)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(what)
if new_url != Backbone.history.fragment
    Backbone.history.navigate(new_url, {trigger: false})
```

Because Backboune.navigate don't execute `navigate` if url didn't change and `trigger` is false by default, I can write it simple like that:

```
new_url = 'info/'+encodeURIComponent(where)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(what)
Backbone.history.navigate(new_url)
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but you might want to take a look at the chapter I wrote on routing in Marionette (available for free: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf) It will show you how to manage routing in a Marionette app without constantly parsing the URL fragment.

Answer (score 0):

`Backbone.history` takes an object when starting. Try this syntax in CoffeeScript:

```
Backbone.history.start
  pushState: false
```

In addition, `pushState` is false by default, so you can just have `Backbone.history.start()`

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Nope :( I used Backbone.history.start() at first with same result.

Comment: Are you clicking on a link with an ref`value? If yes, did you call `e.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: Yes, I use e.preventDefault(). I trigger `do:search` event on clicking or on submiting form, results is the same. Please look Update 2, I think problem is in url itself

Answer (score 0):

Proper URL encoding is required. I couldn't find this in the docs of Backbone related to the router functionality.

I had the same issue, alas with spaces in the query part, i.e.:

```
#app/terms?filter=java ee
```

Together with the encodeURIComponent solution as described in your answer, I also found the following lines of comments in backbone.js (1.0.0), pertaining to the navigate function:

```
// Save a fragment into the hash history, or replace the URL state if the
// 'replace' option is passed. You are responsible for properly URL-encoding
// the fragment in advance.
```